# 403 (Forbidden) error at the console window

Tags: php, wampserver

I am getting 403 (Forbidden) error at the console window when I run any project.

```
    GET http://localhost/icons/blank.gif 403 (Forbidden)
    GET http://localhost/icons/back.gif 403 (Forbidden)
    GET http://localhost/icons/text.gif 403 (Forbidden)
    GET http://localhost/icons/folder.gif 403 (Forbidden)
```

I am using WampServer Version 2.5. Can anybody help me how can I get rid of these error?

Comment: does icons folder and images in it exists in the www folder of wamp?

Comment: Sounds like either 1) your server doesn't have rights to get to those files; or 2) You have incorrectly defined your Apache `allow from` and `deny from` directives. Wamp's context menu has an entry to view the error logs. I'd start with that.

Comment: Can you show us what code you are running please.

Comment: @RiggsFolly it shows even for simple html page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I find the solution:

Edit the httpd-autoindex.conf located in \bin\apache\apache2.4.9\conf\extra

I changed

```
Alias /icons/ "c:/Apache24/icons/"
```

to

```
Alias /icons/ "D:/wamp/bin/apache/apache2.4.9/icons/"
```

and
    
to

```
<Directory "D:/wamp/bin/apache/apache2.4.9/icons/">
```

Comment: A more resiliant solution would be to use `Alias /icons/ "icons/"`

Comment: Or upgrade to WAMPServer 3 http://forum.wampserver.com/read.php?2,123606